# Нужна ли запятая в фразе "Стоит усердно работать, даже если никто не наблюдает"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Я привык выделять запятыми любой оборот с "если", но есть ощущение, что это "даже" может нейтрализовать такую необходимость.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Стоит усердно работать, даже если никто не наблюдает.***

Действительно, запятая перед частицей *даже* ставится(так как это сложное предложение), а между *даже* и последующим полчинительным сюзом — нет.

Запомните: сочетание данной усилительной частицы с подчинительным союзом запятой не разделяется.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_148

> Частица «даже» может стоять перед союзом в сложноподчиненном предложении. В этом случае **запятая перед «даже» ставится, а между «даже» и союзом отсутствует**.
> Но победу, // гений, // можешь праздновать, // даже если ты совсем один, // если у тебя, // светильник разума, // гривенника нет на керосин. Е. Евтушенко, Казанский университет. Она всегда врала, даже когда правду говорила. В. Токарева, Просто свободный вечер.